# Runtime Error 424: Object not Defined"- While Sending Email Using Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, excel, outlook-2013

I am using below code to send multiple emails through outlook, this code is working fine when I use Excel 2007 and Outlook 2007 however when I tried to run same code in Excel 2013 and Outlook 2013 it is throwing an error "Runtime Error 424: Object not Defined" in the below code:

> ```
> Set Doc = olMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
> ```

Can somebody please check below coding and let me know what do I need to change if I want to use same macro in 2013 version?

```
Sub Msmail()

Dim otlApp As Object  
Dim olMail As Object


Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")   
Set olMail = otlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook

    Worksheets("Mail").Select
    ActiveSheet.Calculate

    Total_Site = Range("Total_Site")
    For Site_Count = 1 To Total_Site

    Application.StatusBar = False
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Range("Site_Count") = Site_Count
    ActiveSheet.Calculate

    If Range("Send_Email") = "Y" Then

    Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set olMail = otlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set Doc = olMail.GetInspector.WordEditor   '<~ ERROR 424 HERE

    SendID = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("To_List").Value
    CCID = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("Cc_List").Value
    Subject = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("Subject_Line").Value
    Body = mainWB.Sheets("Summary").Range("Mail_Body").Value
    AttachFile = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("StrPath").Value
    StrPath = ActiveSheet.Range("StrPath").Value

    With olMail

        .To = SendID
        If CCID <> 0 Then
          .CC = CCID
        End If
        .Subject = Subject

        mainWB.Sheets("Summary").Range("Mail_Body").Copy

        Set WrdRng = Doc.Range
       .Display
       WrdRng.Paste

           'StrPath = Range("StrPath").Value

           StrFile = Range("StrFile").Value & "*.*"

            StrFile = Range("StrFile").Value
           .Attachments.Add StrPath & "\" & StrFile

            .Send

    End With
    End If
    Next Site_Count

End Sub
```

Comment: Is `Option Explicit` specified? Seems your code wouldn't even compile with that option, seeing many variables used but not declared anywhere. Is there any reason to late-bind the Outlook type library instead of adding a reference to it in your project and having compile-time type safety, IntelliSense and auto-complete? Having IntelliSense would probably help you with what the available members are, and how they're called. FWIW you're creating two `olMail` objects - one outside the loop, that gets ignored, and one inside the loop.

Comment: I only require olmail objects inside the loop i can remove olmail object outside the loop. But i am having problem while executing "Set Doc = olMail.GetInspector.WordEditor" do i need to define any object or variable for this.

Comment: Yes ,I have defined all the variables in excel

Answer (score 0):

OK - so there appear to be quite a lot of issues with the current code; you have duplication of code and non-dimensioned variables. I have tried to condense the code down, added direct references and this will hopefully make it more readable and (should maybe) work, but it's untested... I don't have the ranges set out in relevant sheets and no data to test it

```
Sub msMail()

    Dim olApp As Object: Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim olMail As Object

    Dim Total_Site As Range, Doc As Variant, WrdRng As Range
    Dim StrPath As String, StrFile As String, Site_Count As Long

    Dim wbMain As Workbook: Set wbMain = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsMail As Worksheet: Set wsMail = wbMain.Worksheets("Mail")
    Dim wsSumm As Worksheet: Set wsSumm = wbMain.Worksheets("Summary")

    With wsMail
        .Calculate ' Not sure why this is included...
        Set Total_Site = Range("Total_Site")
        For Site_Count = 1 To Total_Site.Count
            ''Application.StatusBar = False
            Range("Site_Count") = Site_Count
            If Range("Send_Email") = "Y" Then
                Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                Set Doc = olMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
                If Not Doc Is Nothing Then
                    With olMail
                        .To = wsMail.Range("To_List")
                        .CC = IIf(wsMail.Range("Cc_List") <> 0, wsMail.Range("Cc_List"), "")
                        .Subject = wsMail.Range("Subject_Line")
                        wsSumm.Range("Mail_Body").Copy
                        Set WrdRng = Doc.Range
                        .Display
                        WrdRng.Paste
                        StrPath = wsMail.Range("StrPath")
                        StrFile = wsMail.Range("StrFile")
                        .Attachments.Add StrPath & "\" & StrFile
                        ' .Send
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next Site_Count
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Flephal, Thanks for the help , however i am getting same kind of errors in this code as well. My previous code was executing well if i use Office 2007 (Excel and Outlook) , however same code is throwing errors in Office 2013. I have mentioned types of errors and the codes in which i am getting it , request you to please look into that and let me know can i do to resolve them. Thanks